# If $x+2y+3z=10$ find the maximum value of $x^2y^2z^6$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

If $x+2y+3z=10$ where x,y,z are postive real numbers, find the maximum value of $x^2y^2z^6$.

I started by trying to find some integer solutions. The first thing I found was $(x,y,z)=(1,3,1)$. But the value of $x^2y^2z^6$ was way too small (it was a multiple choice question in the paper I was solving).

The next thing I tried was setting $x=y=z$ because I thought the product of numbers would be highest if they were equal. And I got $x=y=z=\frac{5}{3}$. And so I got $x^2y^2z^6 = (\frac{5}{3})^{10}$

But this answer seems very weird and even my logic is not right, I merely went by intuition.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose $x, y, z$ are positive real number such that $x + 2y + 3z = 1$. Find the maximum value of $xyz^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761322/suppose-x-y-z-are-positive-real-number-such-that-x-2y-3z-1-find-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume $x,y,z$ are non-negative integers. Otherwise, if they are allowed to be negative, we may choose their magnitude to be arbitrarily large.

Write : \begin{align*}
10 &= x + 2y + 3z\\
&= \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2} + y + y + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z}{2}\\
&\geqslant 10\cdot\sqrt[10]{\frac{x}{2} \cdot \frac{x}{2} \cdot y \cdot y \cdot \frac{z}{2} \cdot \frac{z}{2} \cdot \frac{z}{2} \cdot \frac{z}{2} \cdot \frac{z}{2} \cdot \frac{z}{2}}\\
&= 10 \cdot \sqrt[10]{\frac{x^2y^2z^6}{2^8}}\\
\end{align*}

We have used simple AM-GM in the first inequality step. Thus, $x^2y^2z^6 \leqslant 2^8 = 256$ , i.e. its maximum possible value is $256$.

---

The maximum value is attained when : $$\frac{x}{2}=y=\frac{z}{2}\quad\implies\quad x=2y=z\quad\implies\quad (x,y,z) = (2,1,2)$$

Answer (score 2):

$10=x+2y+3z=x+2y+z+z+z\geq 5\sqrt[5]{2xyz^3}$
$xyz^3\leq 16\Longrightarrow x^2y^2z^6\leq 256$
Maximum value is at $x=2y=z$ . It's $(2,1,2)$

Answer (score 1):

Apply weightedAM-GM to $p,q,r$ with frequencies as 2,2,6, then
$$\frac{2p+2q+6r}{10} \ge (p^2 q^2 r^6)^{1/10}~~~~(1)$$
given that $x+2y+3z=10$ choose $p=x/2, q=y, r=z/2$
Inserting them in (1), we get
$$\frac{10}{10} \ge [(x/2)^2 y^2 (z/2)^6]^{1/10} \implies x^2y^2z^6\le 256.$$
Equality holds when $x/2=y=z/2 \implies x=2y,y=1,z=2y.$

Comment: Exponent in first equation should be $1/10$?

Comment: Yes, thanks I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

A.M. $\geq$ G.M.
$$10=x+2y+3z=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+y+y+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2} \geq 10{(\frac{x^2}{4}y^2\frac{z^6}{64})^\frac{1}{10}} $$

$$1\geq (\frac{x^2}{4}y^2\frac{z^6}{64})^\frac{1}{10}$$

$$x^2y^2z^6\leq 2^{10}$$

Equilaty holds when $\frac{x}{2}=y=\frac{z}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've listed this under precalculus, I rather feel like AM/GM is beyond what you'd be expected to know? Possibly not, it's hard to tell. So let's examine a different method.

My early thoughts were this: Simplify anything we can.

(1) Finding the maximum of $x^2y^2z^6$ is the same as finding the maximum of its square root (assuming the maximum is greater than $1$, which we can easily get by putting in random numbers), so we can instead look at $xyz^3$.

(2) We can convert $xyz^3$ to an expression in two variables by solving the first equation for $x$ and substituting:

$$x = 10 - 2y - 3z \implies xyz^3 = yz^3(10-2y-3z) = 10yz^3 - 2y^2z^3 - 3yz^4$$

We look for the maximum of *this* function, $f(y,z) = 10yz^3 - 2y^2z^3 - 3yz^4$, and then calculate $x$ at the end.

Normally to find a maximum, we want to find a place where $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = 0$. But we have two variables here! What are we going to do? We're going to <s>cheat</s> take advantage of partial differentiation. We can differentiate with respect to each variable separately, treating the other *temporarily* as a constant. Man, it sure *feels* like cheating. But it works nicely, and even has its own symbol ($\partial$):

$$
\begin{gather*}
\textstyle \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (10yz^3 - 2y^2z^3 - 3yz^4) = 10z^3-4yz^3-3z^4 = 0 \\
10z^3-4yz^3-3z^4 = 0 \implies 10-4y-3z=0 \implies 4y+3z = 10 \\
\textstyle \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (10yz^3 - 2y^2z^3 - 3yz^4) = 30yz^2 - 6y^2z^2 - 12yz^3 = 0 \\
30yz^2 - 6y^2z^2 - 12yz^3 = 0 \implies 30 - 6y - 12z = 0 \implies 6y + 12z = 30
\end{gather*}
$$

Note that we can safely divide by $z^3$ and $yz^2$ respectively, because we know $x, y, z \neq 0$. We now have a linear system $(4y + 3z = 10, 6y + 12z = 30)$ in two variables. Use your favorite solution method, and you'll get $(y, z) = (1, 2)$, and quick calculations with the original equation gives $x = 2$.

Which is the same answer others have given above, with $\max(x^2y^2z^6) = 256$, and no one had to take the 10th root or 5th power of anything.

Comment: Sorry I can't use calculus to solve the problem.